# Creating histogram by groups for variable in dataframe

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, histogram

I've been trying to compare two histograms by condition (either 1 or 0), but my code does not work. It creates a grey histogram that does not allow me to compare groups. Any clues here? Btw I'm working in an r dataframe.

```
ggplot(my_data, aes(x=GrandNeedMean, fill=Condition)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 0.25, alpha=.5, position = "identity") +
  ggtitle("GrandNeedMean by condition histogram")
```

[Columns in dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNkIX.png)

[Histogram from current code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ON6i6.png)

Comment: Hi. If you could share a sample of `my_data` that would really help. Does `fill = as.factor(Condition)` work?

Comment: Yeah sure. I've added the relevant columns, but I'll add more if that helps? I will try that - thanks!

Comment: Please don't post picture of data. See how to make a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). But as Adam pointed out, it appears your Condition is numeric. If you use `fill=factor(Condition)` then ggplot will treat the value as a categorical variable and show two distinct colors. Numeric scales won't work with the fill= aesthetic for histograms.

Comment: @Adam This might be a dumb question, but what more should I add from the "my_data" dataframe?

Comment: It worked! Thanks guys. I'll start to use reproducible code too - good advice:)